# Retrieving Image from Firebase through a Different View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am working on a Swift project that takes photographs through the AV Camera and saves the images to a Firebase folder in storage. I then want to retrieve those images and run them through an image classifier model to categorized the image as a certain object.

In my project, I have three main view controllers devoted to this purpose. My camera view controller takes the images, the preview view controller allows the viewer to review the image and save it, and my analysis view controller then takes that image, runs it through the model, and then categorizes the image. However, the problem is that whenever I try to look up tutorials for uploading and downloading images, they are always done in the same view controller. However, I would not like to do that because I don't want to clutter my preview view controller with too many actions. Is there a way that I can download the image from a separate view controller? I would preferably like it to be in a download link so that I can then get an image from it and pass it into the Image Classifier Model. If you could kindly provide the code for doing so from start to finish I would appreciate it.

Here is the code I have for uploading my image into the Preview View Controller. Again, I would like to download the image in my Analysis View Controller:

```
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseFirestore

struct MyKeys {
    static let imagesFolder = "imagesFolder"
    static let imagesAnalysis = "imagesAnalysis"
    static let uid = "uid"
    static let imageUrl = "imageUrl"
}

class PreviewViewController: UIViewController {
    func uploadPhoto() {
        let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child(MyKeys.imagesFolder).child("\(imageName)")
        
        if let imageData = image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1) {
            storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
            
                if error != nil {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
                return
                }
                print(metadata as Any)
                
        })
        }
        else {
            let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Unable to Upload Image", preferredStyle: .alert)
            self.present(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but your question isn't a Firebase issue or anything similar, you just don't know how to separate logic and pass data between view controllers. I suggest you take a step back and check out a few tutorials regarding those topic then come back to this issue, since in its current form it's both simple and a broad question with a lot of different solutions.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but the thing that I'm still having trouble with is I don't know how I can get another view controller to retrieve the image last uploaded. That way, as soon as the user uploaded the file, I want it to download as well. Is there a way that I can do that?

Comment: If you're the one uploading the image, you can just pass the image as the argument to the next VC. Or, if downloading is your thing, you can pass the URL as well.